# c++ taking a formula from a string

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

The goal of this program is to take a formula from user input (I used `QLineEdit`) and plot the formula (using `QCustomPlot` for qt). This is the part of the code that I have trouble with:

```
QVector<double> x(10000), y(10000);
for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
{
  double xi = ui->xi_LineEdit->text().toDouble();
  x[i] = xi;
  double yi = ui->yi_LineEdit->text().toDouble();
  y[i] = yi;
}
ui->grafiek->addGraph();
ui->grafiek->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
```

This code obviously does not work right now. How do I take the formula from user input, by example `xi = i/50.0 - 20` and `yi = x[i]*x[i]`, and **process** it?

Comment: sorry, not obvious at all. You need to tell us what the code does and what it is supposed to do

Comment: You really should break the problem down first.  This has nothing to do with Qt.  It has everything to do with taking a string of data, and figuring out what that string represents and if it is a valid math expression, then figure out how to parse the expression, operators, operands, etc.  No Qt is involved in that -- that is computer science.

Comment: No related to Qt. Voted to close this question. You need to learn how to manipulate symbols in formula string. it is not simple. it needs many lines of codes but u can try search for 3rd party library in github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QLineEdit` gives you a `QString` containing a math expression. This type cannot be converted to a `double` unless it contains nothing but a double. For example, the text "10.34" can be converted from a QString to a double, but the text "10.34 - 18 + 2" cannot, because it must be evaluated first.

You need to pass the QLineEdit text to a math expression parser. You could write your own if you only need to handle simple arithmetic. This is a worthwhile learning exercise, and you can find numerous examples online, including on SO. If you need more sophisticated parsing, or are in a hurry, then you can google for `C++ math parser` or similar and use existing code.